# "Select count()" returns wrong value

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am trying to determine if a specific value exists in a Oracle database table.
I used a query with "select count(*)", "select count(1)" and select count(<col_name>)" but keep getting the wrong result. When I use SQL Developer and run the query I get zero for the count. However, in the DAL, I get 1. I am guessing it is returning the number of row rather than the count itself. I tried both executeScalar() and ExecuteReader().

```
public override bool zipExists(string sZipCode)
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(this.OraDataConnectionString);
    OracleCommand oraCmd = new OracleCommand();
    decimal iNumEntries = 0;
    string sQuery = "select count(ZIPCODEID) as ZipCount from ZIPCODE where ZIPCODE = :ZipCode";
    SetOraCommandType(oraCmd, CommandType.Text, sQuery);

    conn.Open();
    oraCmd.Connection = conn;
    oraCmd.BindByName = true;
    AddParamToOraCmd(oraCmd, "ZipCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 11, ParameterDirection.Input, sZipCode);

    using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(this.OraDataConnectionString))
    {
        oraCmd.Connection = cn;
        cn.Open();
        iNumEntries = (decimal)oraCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    return iNumEntries > 0;
```

also tried:

```
    OracleDataReader sqlReader = oraCmd.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        if (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            if (sqlReader["ZipCount"] != DBNull.Value)
                iNumEntries = Convert.ToInt16(sqlReader["ZipCount"]);
        }
    }
}
return iNumEntries > 0;
```

Comment: what are you getting when you return the count ..? what are you expecting to return.. also `SELECT count(*) from ZipCode where ZIPCODE = :zipcode` should work.. are there duplicate zipcode..? have you tried doing this in Oracle Sql Developer and using a Order by clause..?

Comment: when I run in in SQL developer, I get 0 (specifically, it shows column ZipCount and the value of 0). When I trace the code, iNumEntries is 1 which results in the function returning true when it should return false.

Comment: what are you typing exactly in the sql developer can you show that

Comment: select count(ZIPCODEID) as ZipCount from ZIPCODE where ZIPCODE = '64141075454';  when I trace the code, the :ZipCode parameter has the exact same value of 64141075454

Comment: I try you code on my table but pointing to some column and giving a 
`select count(EN_Qty) as ZipCount from PSLAT.FSDEV.dbo.PS_EN_GEN_INTFC_BI where EN_Qty = '2600'` works on my end so where in the code exactly are you experiencing an issue..? fyi I replaced my table with your query and assigned a value to the where clause.. so you query looks right.. however I would do an order by query to see if you perhaps are missing a zipcode..also `oraCmd.ExecuteScalar()` returns only 1 row so make sure you are not returning more than one row..oracle is funny like that

Comment: the query when run in SQL dveloper works fine, it returns one row and the value of count is zero, as it should be. The problem is in C# code where iNumEntries instead of being zero ends up being 1. I am gussing it is returning number of rows returned by the query rather than the value itself. I also tried to use OracleReader to read the value directly rather than rely on value returned by ExecuteScalar, but he same thing happens!

Comment: change your code to the following 
`object bExists = oraCmd.ExecuteScalar();`
`var bexists = bExists != DBNull.Value && result != null;` or change your code to check for row.count > 0 if true then you know the zipcode was found

Comment: Found my issue, had nothing to do with the code! There were some uncommitted changes in SQL Developer so even though SQL developer would return 0 for the zip code, the code would return 1 because delete was not committed. If you add your answer as an answer and  not comment, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try you code on my table but pointing to some column and giving a select count(EN_Qty) as ZipCount from PSLAT.FSDEV.dbo.PS_EN_GEN_INTFC_BI where EN_Qty = '2600' works on my end so where in the code exactly are you experiencing an issue..? fyi I replaced my table with your query and assigned a value to the where clause.. so you query looks right.. however I would do an order by query to see if you perhaps are missing a zipcode..also oraCmd.ExecuteScalar() returns only 1 row so make sure you are not returning more than one row..oracle is funny like that

change your code to the following

```
object bExists = oraCmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
var bexists = bExists != DBNull.Value && result != null;
```

or change your code to check for row.count > 0 if true then you know the zipcode was found. Remember when making changes to Sql scripts or stored procedures in Oracle, you need to Compile the changes otherwise the changes will be visible to you when looking at the code but not to the caller trying to execute the stored proc.